# AWS CLI - Put contents of a file in a single attribute value within a DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I have some C# code that successfully puts contents of a text file into a DynamoDB table attribute value:

```
var content = File.ReadAllText("file.txt");
var dynamoDB = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(region);
var request = new PutItemRequest
{
  TableName = "mytable",
  Item = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>() { 
    { "mykey", new AttributeValue { S = "file.txt" } },
    { "content", new AttributeValue { S = content } },
  },
};
var response = await dynamoDB.PutItemAsync(request);
```

This works as expected, and the contents of `file.txt` ends up in the table.

How do I do this using AWS CLI? i.e. how to I put the contents of a file into a single attribute value within a DynamoDB table, using AWS CLI?

`aws dynamodb put-item --item` is no good because that expects the contents of the file to be json records.

Answer (score 1):

read the file into a variable and save as a json file

```
 mykey="file.txt"
 content=$(cat out.txt)
 jq -n \
    --arg key "$mykey" \
    --arg value "$content"  \
    '{mykey: $key, content: $value}' > item.json
```

then use the aws command e.g.

```
 aws dynamodb put-item \
    --table-name MyTable \
    --item file://item.json
```